# Tensorflow import error in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, importerror

Initially, the code worked, but when I restart it again in notepad (Restart&Run All), I get an import error ImportError for tensorflow as follows:

```
cannot import name 'export_saved_model' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.saving.saved_model'
```

As a possible solution to the problem, uninstall the library on the command line in order to reinstall it. An attempt to do this via conda did not give any result (I got stuck at the solving environment stage: the pointer rotated, but then nothing happened). I achieved the solution using pip. And I got a second error - now with a different import:

```
cannot import name 'tf2' from 'tensorflow.python' (unknown location)
```

What should I do?

Comment: Can you show us the imports?

Comment: Первоначально блокнот ругался на следующую строку:
`import tensorflow as tf`
Теперь ошибка в этой строке
`from keras.datasets import cifar10`

Comment: Please use english, `tf.keras.experimental.export_saved_model(model, path)` is that the way you used?

Comment: No, I was just trying to import a module:
`from keras.datasets import cifar10`
However, I received the specified error

Comment: Now the first problem is solved: tensorflow is working, but the remote keras is not installed by the `conda install keras command`:
`PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- keras==2.4.0`

At the same time, there is a disorder here: `Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.`

In the end, the system offers me the following:
`To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to
https://anaconda.org
and use the search bar at the top of the page.`

Comment: As a result, I get the message: `No module named 'keras' `

Answer (score 0):

Actually, at first tensorflow "swore", after its" repair " - keras, but in the end the sequential execution of the commands `pip uninstall tensorflow`, `pip uninstall keras` and after them - the re-installation of modules helped.
There were experiments with a virtual environment, but these solutions turned out to be superfluous